# how can i return an array from a function

Tags: c

How can I return an array from a function, I am trying to perform `(3*3)*(3*1)` matrix multiplication using this translation function and how can i get an array out of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int* translation(int x, int y, int tx, int ty) {
    static int res[3][1] = {0}, xy[3][1] = {{x},{y},{1}};
    int tm[3][3] = {{1,0, tx}, {0,1,ty}, {0,0,1}};
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            res[i][0] += tm[i][j]*xy[j][0];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int *arr[3][1];
    arr = translation(5, 5);
    printf("%d %d %d", arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pack it in a `struct` - There is no other way of "returning an array". You could return a `struct { int*; size_t len; }` and then the caller would know...

Comment: If the array is of a known and constant size, you can wrap it in a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can I return an array from a function"*

You can't.

The language has no such concept.

You'll have to return something including the length to give the user of the function the information. In C the idiomatic approach is to supply a pointer to the function and to get a value (via that pointer) in return:

```
size_t no_idea;
void function(void *data, &no_idea);
```

As a user of this function you'd have to read `no_idea` before judging.

Comment: i better use struct then

Answer (score 0):

you question is missing a lot of information like what you want to do with your code, the variable named `xy` isn't defined anywhere in your code, and so on...

but for clarification, if your result matrix is of unknown size, you can wrap your array into a `struct`, if you don't know what is the `struct`, you can refer to [this small tutorial about struct in c](https://www.w3schools.com/c/c_structs.php#:%7E:text=Structures%20(also%20called%20structs)%20are,%2C%20char%2C%20etc.), so your struct maybe look like something like this:

```
typedef struct Array_t{
    size_t arrSize_x;
    size_t arrSize_y;
    int **arr;
}Array_t;
```

where `arr` is your matrix of unknown size which will be created dynamically and `arrSize_x`, `arrSize_y` are your matrix dimensions.

so in order to create a matrix of unknow size at compile time , you should create it dynamically in the heap memory using functions like `calloc` or `malloc`, although in `C99`, it allowed created arrays statically of unknown size during compile time but it's not the case with `struct` as the `struct` once defined, your array is created and you **cannot** do something like this:

```
typedef struct Array_t{
    size_t arrSize_x;
    size_t arrSize_y;
    int arr[arrSize_x][arrSize_y];
}Array_t;
```

but if the size of the array is known you can do something like this:

```
typedef struct Array_t{
    int arr[3][1];
}Array_t;
```

to create a dynamic array, you will find in the next example code something like this:

```
// rows are stored in heap memory and initiated with zeros
res.arr = (int**) calloc(res.arrSize_x, sizeof(int));

// columns are also stored in heap memory and initiated with zeros
for (int i = 0; i < res.arrSize_x; ++i) {
    res.arr[i] = (int *) calloc(res.arrSize_y, sizeof(int));
}
```

where `res.arr` is a pointer pointing to an array of pointers and the next diagram may simplify my explanation where the next graph expresses the created matrix in heap memory for `arr` of size **3 x 1**:

[image]

while if the size is known, so the explanation diagram may look like this:

[image]

and when you return, you can either return by **value** or by **reference**, but if you are going to return a `struct` by reference then you should declare it as `static`.

so you can do something like this (for clarification purposes, size of matrix is unknown):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Array_t{
    size_t arrSize_x;
    size_t arrSize_y;
    int **arr;
}Array_t;

Array_t translation(int x, int y, int tx, int ty) {
    // create a struct holding the array
    Array_t res;
    res.arrSize_x = 3;
    res.arrSize_y = 1;

    // rows are stored in heap memory and initiated with zeros
    res.arr = (int**) calloc(res.arrSize_x, sizeof(int));

    // columns are also stored in heap memory and initiated with zeros
    for (int i = 0; i < res.arrSize_x; ++i) {
        res.arr[i] = (int *) calloc(res.arrSize_y, sizeof(int));
    }

    res.arr[0][0] = 1;
    res.arr[1][0] = 2;
    res.arr[2][0] = 3;


    return res;
}

int main()
{
    Array_t array;
    // 1, 2, 3, 4 are dummy parameters
    array = translation(1, 2, 3, 4);
    printf("elements are :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.arrSize_x; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.arrSize_y; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", array.arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
elements are :
1
2
3
```

but if size of matrix is known then you can do something like this (for clarification purposes, size of matrix is known):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Array_t{
    int arr[3][1];
}Array_t;

Array_t translation(int x, int y, int tx, int ty) {
    // create a struct holding the array
    Array_t res;
    
    res.arr[0][0] = 1;
    res.arr[1][0] = 2;
    res.arr[2][0] = 3;


    return res;
}

int main()
{
    Array_t array;
    // 1, 2, 3, 4 are dummy parameters
    array = translation(1, 2, 3, 4);
    printf("elements are :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", array.arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the ouput:

```
elements are :
1
2
3
```